# Reusing JSON structure making relative references in the same document

Tags: templates, macros, jsonschema

I'm trying to reuse a structure I previously created. In the example below it is `basic_defense`.

```
{
  "templates": {
    "basic_defense": [
      {
        "unit": "laser_tower_v1",
        "priority": "high",
        "how_many": 4
      },
      {
        "unit": "anti_air_v1",
        "priority": "low",
        "condition": {
          "air": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "buildings": {
    "basic_vehicle_factory_v1": {
      "defenses": "templates.basic_defense",
      "priority": "high"
    },
    "basic_aircraft_factory_v1": {
      "defenses": "templates.basic_defense",
      "priority": "medium"
    },
    "basic_naval_factory_v1": {
      "defenses": "templates.basic_defense",
      "priority": "medium"
    }
  }
}
```

The string `"templates.basic_defense"` is not the correct way to reuse the structure I previously created, it is just a place to make more clear where I would like it to be reused.

There is a game that I play where unit configuration files are a bit tedious to edit because I end up copying the same defense structure over and over again. If I could create a basic block and reference whenever I need that.

Post notes: I'm not a programmer and these configuration files I'm talking about are unmaintained by the community that created the game.

I searched for JSON schema support for templates and macros, but I did not find anything, or I couldn't understand the terminologies or jargon to find a solution to what I needed to accomplish.

Comment: I decided to use [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) . To make it work we need just provide a function to avoid the default HTML escaping, ex.: `mustache.render(template, view, {}, { escape: str => str, tags: ['"{{', '}}"'] })`. Then I can use the pattern {{name}} like `"defenses": "{{basic_defense}}"`. One thing to note is that I've separated the `template` and `view` in two files. Maybe I'll write a solution if no one shows me how to do it just using the features available in the JSON Schema specification.

Comment: JSON Schema isn't the right tool for what you're wanting to do.  It's designed for data validation, but you're looking for transformation.

Comment: https://jsonnet.org/ might be a good tool to look into for this kind of thing.